# aweber connecting to my own database and updating subscribers info

Tags: database, api, aweber

I wanted to know is it possible to "connect" - in some way Awebers subscribers list to my own database. I couldnt find anything in documentation but wanted to ask just to check. So the reason I want this is because if any of subscribers unsubscribe at any time I want to "pass" that information to my own database.

Is this possible and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use our API to connect to your database. You can view the documentation for our API here:

https://labs.aweber.com/

You'd need to use the subscribers endpoint. A GET request on that endpoint will return a JSON encoded response with all subscribers on a given list. You could parse the information from that response and compare it to your database.

To get all subscribers that are unsubscribed, you'd want to use our API's find method. Pass in a status of "unsubscribed" as a parameter with your request, and you'll get all unsubscribed addresses. You could then loop over them and mark them as unsubscribed in your database.

Our API has libraries for Python or PHP, but since it's REST you could use whatever language you wished as long as it has support for HTTP requests. Similarly, many popular databases have support for programmatically updating information, so you should be able to find documentation for those online.

Comment: I need too, but don't want to call APi to check subscribers status. I can't find anything about aweber webhook...doesn't exist webhook in aweber?